# identity provider - Build identity provider manual on local

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml

I'm using spring security saml to implement SSO. For testing, I used ssocircle as idp. But now, I want to control authenticating by myself, that means, can I build idp host on my local by using spring security (user info will be stored in my database).

Note: OpenAM is not my expectation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to build your own IDP because it is a complicated process, even if you use a library like opensaml, your best option would be to install Shibboleth Idp, there are many tutorials online, some on the shibboleth.net website and some on other websites. These two are very good tutorials:

1- https://books.google.ie/books?id=AeBaAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=Investigation+and+implementation+of+Shibboleth+SSO+authentication+mechanism&source=bl&ots=g6A_kstwJ2&sig=Nr4AR6WKillYyIl5UQaUszkTDB8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibtvL51tvJAhUI_A4KHb18DUYQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q&f=true

2- https://tuakiri.ac.nz/confluence/display/Tuakiri/Installing+a+Shibboleth+3.x+IdP